# MySQL/PHP update query error

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm running a query to update a small group of 'items' in a table, from PHP.
Running the code with "Sequel Pro" executes it perfectly, while running it on PHP using mysql("query here"); fails miserably.

Is there anything wrong with my query?

```
UPDATE `service_joblocation` 
   SET  `in_use` =  '1', 
        `in_use_since` =  '1283488686', 
        `in_use_currentcount` =  `in_use_currentcount`+1, 
        `in_use_historicalcount`= `in_use_historicalcount`+1 
  WHERE `id` = 5 
  LIMIT 1;

UPDATE `service_joblocation` 
   SET `in_use` =  '1', 
       `in_use_since` =  '1283488686', 
       `in_use_currentcount` = `in_use_currentcount`+1, 
       `in_use_historicalcount` = `in_use_historicalcount`+1 
 WHERE `id`=16 
  LIMIT 1;

UPDATE `service_joblocation` 
   SET  `in_use` =  '1', 
        `in_use_since` = '1283488686', 
        `in_use_currentcount` = `in_use_currentcount`+1, 
        `in_use_historicalcount` = `in_use_historicalcount`+1 
  WHERE `id`=18 
   LIMIT 1;

UPDATE `service_items` SET  `checkin_user`='9', `checkin_date`='1283488686', `location`='5' WHERE `id`=576;
UPDATE `service_items` SET  `checkin_user`='9', `checkin_date`='1283488686', `location`='16' WHERE `id`=577;
UPDATE `service_items` SET  `checkin_user`='9', `checkin_date`='1283488686', `location`='18' WHERE `id`=578;
UPDATE `service_jobs` SET `checkin_date`='1283488686', `checkin_user`='9',`checkin_department`='1',`checkin_client_person`='0', `items_x`=`items_x`+1 WHERE `id`='518' LIMIT 1;
UPDATE `service_jobs` SET `checkin_date`='1283488686', `checkin_user`='9',`checkin_department`='1',`checkin_client_person`='0', `items_x`=`items_x`+1 WHERE `id`='518' LIMIT 1;
UPDATE `service_jobs` SET `checkin_date`='1283488686', `checkin_user`='9',`checkin_department`='1',`checkin_client_person`='0', `items_x`=`items_x`+1 WHERE `id`='518' LIMIT 1;
```

This is the output message...

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'UPDATE
>   `service_joblocation` SET  `in_use` = 
>   '1', `in_use_since` =  '1283488686' at
>   line 2

Comment: Are there duplicate `service_joblocation.id` values?  If not, there's no value to having `LIMIT 1` at the end...  And why did you include additional UPDATE statements that the error doesn't relate to?

Comment: Your queries look OK to me. The problem probably lies in your PHP code. Could you post that too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only pass a single statement to mysql_query().

There are other functions/methods like e.g. [mysqli::multi_query()](http://docs.php.net/mysqli.multi-query) but not for the old mysql extension.

Comment: Cheers :D

I was freaking out because the query works fine in the application.. I guess it must pass each query separately.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the PHP code which executes the query (I assume you meant mysql_query()). The query looks fine to me at a glance, but I think it may be preceded by something that is incorrect, such as an unintentional quotation mark or a brace.

Answer (score 0):

What are the data types of service_joblocation.in_use and service_joblocation.in_use_since? if they are numbers, try removing the quotation marks, i.e.

```
UPDATE `service_joblocation` 
SET  `in_use` =  1, 
     `in_use_since` =  1283488686, 
     `in_use_currentcount` =  `in_use_currentcount`+1, 
     `in_use_historicalcount`= `in_use_historicalcount`+1 
WHERE `id` = 5 
LIMIT 1;
```