# mysql UPDATE query does not run

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I want to update information. when I use the below in code is not working what is wrong in my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $sql = "UPDATE  `food`.`food_item` 
    SET `food_name` =  '$_POST[food_name]',
        `food_price` =  '$_POST[food_price]',
        `food_cat` =  '$_POST[food_category]' 
        WHERE  `food_item`.`id` ='$_POST[id]';";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("query not");

    header("Location: product_info.php") ;
}
```

Comment: add you db connection `mysql_query($sql, $your_connection) ` . btw you may start to learn PDO connection as what your using is deprecated

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: Also, please take a look at http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/essential-newbies-guide-sql-injections-and-manipulating-data-mysql-database-0133921/ for why you **really** do not want to put _POST data straight into your sql.

Comment: Try to remove the semicolon inside the '$sql' string

Comment: error message in "query not run"

Comment: `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); `

Comment: plus, your POST arrays may not be set or empty. Use error reporting and display to find out. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: also, since we don't know which MySQL API you're using to connect with, make sure you are not mixing them. `mysqli_` and `mysql_` and PDO do not intermix with each other.

Comment: @NitolBiswas Update this line `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` And write error message here TNQ ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL/PHP update query error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633100/mysql-php-update-query-error)

Answer (score 6):

If you have a form `input` like,

```
<input type="text" name="product_name" />
```

You should get the value by,

```
 $_POST['product_name'];
```

> Is your form method is *POST* for *GET*?

If your method type is `POST`, you should get it like `$_POST['input_name']`

If your method type is `GET`, you should get it like `$_GET['input_name']`

> Does all your input name you mentioned in html matches in php code?

Eg : If you have a form with input type,

```
  <input type="text" name="product_name" />
```

Then, in php code, you should get it with what you entered in `name` attribute

```
   $_POST['product_name'] OR $_GET['product_name']
```

Not something like,

```
   $_POST['prod_name'] OR $_GET['prod_name']
```

Try this,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])
{
 $food_name = $_POST['food_name'];
 $food_price = $_POST['food_price'];
 $food_cat = $_POST['food_category']; 
 $id = $_POST['id'];

 // do not directly input the form data to sql, filter it by a special function mysqli_real_escape_string
// eg : $food_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['food_price']);
// before executing the query, try to echo the each form input and sql query for clear picture.

$sql = "UPDATE  `food`.`food_item` SET `food_name` =  '$food_name',`food_price` =  '$food_price',`food_cat` =  '$food_cat' WHERE  `food_item`.`id` ='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if($result)
{
    //header("Location: product_info.php") ;
    echo "success";
}
else
{
   echo "fail";
 }
}
else
{
  echo "form not submitted";
  // use header to redirect to old page again
}
```

**WARNING :**

`mysql` is deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

**Note :**

`$db` is a database connection variable. You need to setup like

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database_name");
```

Look it's not `mysql_connect`, its **mysqli_connect**. Replace the db value according to your needs.

Comment: *You should get the value by,
 `$_POST['product_name'];`

NOT
 `$_POST[product_name];`* - Although it's not good practice, their POST arrays in their values are perfectly valid. However, OP may not be telling us everything. We also do not know which MySQL API they are using to connect with.

Comment: Why you want to declare a new variable for assigning this post variables which consumes more memory?

Comment: Remember, we also don't know what their HTML form looks like neither. They may not have name attributes for any of their elements, including their submit button, which their code execution relies completely inside that conditional statement. Plus, if their form's method is GET, then that will also contribute to a silent failure. *Think ahead* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I agree. I'll try to add that too.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code to find the error.

```
echo mysql_error(); exit;
```

after following code.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql)
```

Comment: I didn't see comment.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the array variables inside double quoted string, either do by enclosing them in curly brackets or put it outside the double quotes and append as a string. Here you try adding curly brackets like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $sql = "UPDATE  `food`.`food_item` 
    SET `food_name` =  '{$_POST['food_name']}',
        `food_price` =  '{$_POST['food_price']}',
        `food_cat` =  '{$_POST['food_category']}' 
        WHERE  `food_item`.`id` ='{$_POST['id']}';";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("query not");

    header("Location: product_info.php") ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just echo $sql; Check what are the actual values in the query. Copy & run it in MYSQL query.

I think that you applied back ticks () on field names `food_name` . Remove back ticks & **replace it with  single quote ( ' )**